# Django - Making an Ajax request

Tags: ajax, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-urls

Im having a hard time figuring out how to integrate this ajax request into my view. I'm still learning how to integrate django with ajax requests.

My first question would be: Does the ajax request need to have its own dedicated URL?

In my case I am trying to call it on a button to preform a filter(Preforms a query dependent on what is selected in the template). I have implemented this using just django but it needs to make new request everytime the user preforms a filter which I know is not efficient.

I wrote the most basic function using JQuery to make sure the communication is there. Whenever the user changed the option in the select box it would print the value to the console. As you will see below in the view, I would to call the ajax request inside this view function, if this is possible or the correct way of doing it.

### JQuery - Updated

```
$("#temp").change( function(event) {
    var filtered = $(this).val();
    console.log($(this).val());
    $.ajax({
        url : "http://127.0.0.1:8000/req/ajax/", 
        type : "GET", 
        data : { 
            'filtered': filtered
        }, 
        dataType: 'json',

        success: function(data){
            console.log(data)
        },
        error: function(xhr, errmsg, err){
            console.log("error")
            console.log(error_data)
        }
    });
```

### Views.py

```
def pending_action(request):
    requisition_status = ['All', 'Created', 'For Assistance', 'Assistance Complete', 'Assistance Rejected']
    FA_status = RequisitionStatus.objects.get(status='For Assistance')

    current_status = 'All'
    status_list = []

    all_status = RequisitionStatus.objects.all()
    status_list = [status.status for status in all_status]

    # This is where I am handling the filtering currently
    if request.GET.get('Filter') in status_list: 
        user_req_lines_incomplete = RequisitionLine.objects.filter(Q(parent_req__username=request.user) & Q(status__status=request.GET.get('Filter')))
        current_status = request.GET.get('Filter')
    else:
        user_req_lines_incomplete = RequisitionLine.objects.filter(parent_req__username=request.user).exclude(status__status='Completed')

    user_reqs = Requisition.objects.filter(par_req_line__in=user_req_lines_incomplete).annotate(aggregated_price=Sum('par_req_line__total_price'),
                                                                                                header_status=Max('par_req_line__status__rating'))
    return render(request, 'req/pending_action.html', { 'user_reqs':user_reqs, 
                                                        'user_req_lines_incomplete':user_req_lines_incomplete, 
                                                        'requisition_status':requisition_status, 
                                                        'current_status':current_status,
                                                        'FA_status':FA_status}) 

def filter_status(request):
    status = request.GET.get('Filter')
    data = {
        'filtered': RequisitionLine.objects.filter(Q(parent_req__username=request.user) & Q(status__status=status)),
        'current_status': status
    }
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

### Urls.py

```
path('pending/', views.pending_action, name='pending_action')
```

Comment: Your view returns an HTML document (since it renders an HTML template), whereas you probably want the view called by the ajax request to return a JSON document of just the variables needed. It is possible to write a view that returns both HTML and JSON depending on the requested content-type, but usually, since the requests are quite different, you should use a different view at a different URL (e.g. `/api/v1.0/req/pending/`). You can create a common function that's used by both views to avoid code duplication.

Comment: @dirkgroten I believe I understand. Basically I am going to have to remove the GET request section in the code above because that is going to be handled in a new function that returns the JSON Response. The view function above will only be meant to render the page initially.

Comment: correct, unless you want people to be able to reach the initial page pre-filtered (e.g. /req/pending/?Filter=For%20Assistance), and change the filter once on the page. That depends if there might be links in your website to a pre-filtered page. Then I'd do the filtering in a seperate function used by both views.

Comment: Note also that your javascript code will have to change the DOM in-place: remove/add the elements that need to be shown.

Comment: @dirkgroten I made some updates to the code but with no luck. I cant even get my console output to show anymore. I have set `id="temp"` in my template for the options in the `select` tag. Can you possibly take a look if im on the right track?

Comment: First the data you submit in your Ajax GET should have the same key as the one you’re checking in your view: `Filter`.  Second you don’t want to send back a QuerySet of Django models in your response, but a dictionary that can be serialized into JSON. Two ways to do that: add a method `serialize_for_api()` to your model that returns a dict or add `.values(“key1”, “key2”, etc)` to your Queryset to return a dict directly. Either way make sure `data` can be serialized before passing it to `JsonResponse`

Answer (score 0):

First: you have to divide your template to unchangeable part and the part that you want to modify with your filter.

Second: for your goal you can use render_to_string. See the followning link https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/templates/#usage

code example (views.py):

```
cont = {
    'request': request, #important key-value
    'your_models_instances': your_models_instances
}
html = render_to_string('your_filter_template.html', cont)
return_dict = {'html': html}
return JsonResponse(return_dict)
```

In your js file you need to determine relative url "{% url 'name in yours url file'%}" 
And in success you need to add next line:

```
success: function(data){
  $(".filter-block").html(data.html);
}
```

i hope it will help you! Good luck!